# Web Scraping For Loop Issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i have an issue with collecting all the data in the website. when i run my code it only prints out the first entry. And it should print out every Song, Artist, and Rank. Also It doesn't show on Csv.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv


    my_url = "https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100"
    headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
   Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'
   }
   r = requests.get(my_url)
   page_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

   filename = "Billboard100.csv"
   csv_writer = csv.writer(open(filename, 'w'))

   Chart = page_soup.findAll('ol', class_='chart-list__elements')
   BB = []
   for item in Chart:
         Song = item.find('span', class_='chart-element__information__song text--truncate color--primary').text.strip()
         Artist = item.find('span', class_='chart-element__information__artist text--truncate color--secondary').text.strip()
         Rank = item.find('span', class_='chart-element__rank__number').text.strip()
       Billboard = {
         'Song': Song,
         'Artist': Artist,
         'Rank': Rank,
}
       BB.append(Billboard)

       print(BB)

       with open("Billboard100.csv", "w",
          newline="") as infile:
       writer = csv.writer(infile)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code Char length was one. Use `Chart = page_soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'chart-list__element display--flex'})` to select all the entity.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv


my_url = "https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'
   }
r = requests.get(my_url)
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

filename = "Billboard100.csv"
csv_writer = csv.writer(open(filename, 'w'))

Chart = page_soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'chart-list__element display--flex'})

BB = []
for item in Chart:
   Song = item.find('span', class_='chart-element__information__song text--truncate color--primary').text.strip()
   Artist = item.find('span', class_='chart-element__information__artist text--truncate color--secondary').text.strip()
   Rank = item.find('span', class_='chart-element__rank__number').text.strip()
   Billboard = {
         'Song': Song,
         'Artist': Artist,
         'Rank': Rank,
}
   BB.append(Billboard)

   print(BB)

with open("Billboard100.csv", "w",newline="") as infile:
   writer = csv.writer(infile)
   for row in BB:
      writer.writerow([row])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't well indented. In python, always check your indentation if some code doesn't run at all. [official doc reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation)

```py
for item in Chart:
         Song = item.find('span', class_='chart-element__information__song text--truncate color--primary').text.strip()
         Artist = item.find('span', class_='chart-element__information__artist text--truncate color--secondary').text.strip()
         Rank = item.find('span', class_='chart-element__rank__number').text.strip()
       Billboard = {
```

should be

```py
for item in Chart:
       Song = item.find('span', class_='chart-element__information__song text--truncate color--primary').text.strip()
       Artist = item.find('span', class_='chart-element__information__artist text--truncate color--secondary').text.strip()
       Rank = item.find('span', class_='chart-element__rank__number').text.strip()
       Billboard = {
```